# How to initialize interface in the mainActivity

Tags: java, android, interface, bluetooth

I have a mainActivity which uses bluetooth, and I have another class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter. What I want to do is, when a specific action occurs
in the mainActivity class, the bluetooth adapter should be passed to the class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter.

To achieve that, I've created an interface IBTAdapterPasser as shown below and I've passed the adapter from the mainActivity to the iBTAdapterPasser as shown below.
My question is, how should I initialize the iBTAdapterObserver object in the mainActivity?

**IBTAdapterPasser**:

```
public interface IBTAdapterPasser {
    public void onDicoveryFinished(BluetoothAdapter btAdapter);
}
```

**in the mainActivity class**:

```
this.iBTAdapterObserver.onDicoveryFinished(this.mBTAdapter);
```

**MyExpandableListAdapter class**

```
@Override
public void onDicoveryFinished(BluetoothAdapter btAdapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mBTAdapter = btAdapter;
}
```

Comment: did you got any solution..?

Answer (score 0):

This way

```
IBTAdapterPasser interface;
interface = (IBTAdapterPasser) this;
```

You should pass bluetooth object as below from main activity

```
interface.onDicoveryFinished(btAdapter)
```

Comment: i tried it, but i received " classcastException:cant cast to com.example.XXX.IBTAdapterPasser". can u please tell me how to solve it

Comment: i think interface is not suitable in this scenario

Comment: You should prepare one public method in that adapter class with BluetoothAdapter as parameter

Comment: this way you will get a classCastException